# Issue with presenting ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm using a UIViewcontroller as a custom to show alert on the screen,
this viewcontroller just contain a custom popup of static height and constraint added to leading, trailing and bottom with 0 constant value,

it is presenting fine from bottom, but when it presents it shows a transparent black background  presenting with my popup, even I set the parent view background as clear color
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlZdT.png)
[image]

I just want to slide my popup view to slides in

how can I do that, please check the video for reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let viewController = yourVC.instantiate(.customStoryboard)
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
viewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```